# Swift 2 How to encode from ASCII to Hexadecimal

Tags: string, hex, ascii, converters, swift2

I have a simple ASCII string and i want to convert it to hexadecimal (base16). I'm using xCode 7 (so i'm on IOS9) but i can't find any solution anywhere.

I tried to change the format of my string:

```
StringToConvert(String(format: "%02hhx", $0))
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".utf8.map{ $0 }.reduce("") {
    $0 + String($1, radix: 16, uppercase: false)
}
```

modify it by your needs

```
"ABCD".utf8.map{ $0 }.reduce("") {
    $0 + "0x" + String($1, radix: 16, uppercase: false) + " "
}
// 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer above. 
Just for clarification, it's implemented like this:

```
let hexRepresentation = myASCIIString.utf8.map{ $0 }.reduce("") { $0 + String($1, radix: 16, uppercase: false) }
```