# How to convert ASCII to hex in Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift

I have converted the string "UK" into hex using code below. How can I convert it to hex?

```
    let str = auxText
    let bytes = str.utf8
    var buffer = [UInt8](bytes)
    buffer[0] = buffer[0] + UInt8(1)
    print("ascii value is",buffer)
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229505/how-to-convert-an-int-to-hex-string-in-swift

Comment: Similar question can be found in [Swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884783/swift-2-how-to-encode-from-ascii-to-hexadecimal) and [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441684/convert-ascii-to-hex-and-back-in-swift-for-linux) research, take a look and try. Then you can avoid to be marked as duplicate.

Comment: not working.My ascii value is [85,75],i am not getting desired value

Comment: What *hex* form do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4, you can convert your ascii encoded `string` to data with

```
string.data(using: .ascii)
```

To convert the data to hex or decimal you can use the following extensions:

```
extension Data {

    var hexString: String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }

    var decimalString: String {
        return map { String(format: "%d", $0) }.joined()
    }

}
```

Your test string "UK"

```
let string = "UK"
```

Evaluates with

```
let hexString = string.data(using: .ascii)!.hexString
```

To

```
554b
```

And with

```
let decimalString = string.data(using: .ascii)!.decimalString
```

To

```
8575
```

Both results are correct, you can look them up in any ASCII table.